# Is it possible to pass operations as arguments without having to declare a global function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, function

I am trying to distribute some calculations into different threads. Most of those calculations take couple lines of code but they take time to process.

For the sake of readability, I do not want to declare a global function for every piece of code that will be threaded.

Is it possible to call a thread using a notation similar to the following?

```
thread t1( 
          for(int i=0;i<largeNumber;i++){
              operation1;
              operation2;
              ...
          }                                );//End of t1
//other threads
t1.join();
```

In other words, can I pass a function as an argument, without having to define it in global scope?

(I'm sorry if this is a basic question, I just couldn't find the right words to search for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lambda functions:

```
thread t1( [] () { // This is lambda
          for(int i=0;i<largeNumber;i++){
              operation1;
              operation2;
              ...
          } });//End of t1
//other threads
t1.join();
```